# Whatsapp Business Cloud API - retrieve messages

Tags: api, whatsapp

If I have the wamid, is there a way to retrieve all of the message info including its content via the API?

Comment: you will get the content of the received messages in webhook only, you can not get your sent messages' content.

Comment: Is it possible to see the content in another way? For example on a cellphone using whatsapp with the sending phone number ?

Comment: I don't know, you can check by yourself by adding that SIM card to your cellphone.